# Did Flamel choose to give up the Sorcerer's stone?

Tags: harry-potter

So Flamel obviously transferred the Philosopher's stone to Dumbledore in some way. It probably was too dangerous to just be left out.

But was he forced to give it up? Or did he give it up of his own free will?

Comment: is this not essentially a dupe? http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/109364/why-didnt-flamel-make-more-than-one-philosophers-stone (as much as I hate linking in any way to HPaMoR)

Comment: Ummm... no. This is about the one sorcerer's stone, that one is a "why not" question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

He gave it up of his own free will after being persuaded of the danger his invention posed to the world.

> ‘Not the Stone, boy, you – the effort involved nearly killed you. For one terrible moment there, I was afraid it had. As for the Stone, it has been destroyed.’
>   ‘Destroyed?’ said Harry blankly. ‘But your friend – Nicolas Flamel –’
>   ‘Oh, you know about Nicolas?’ said Dumbledore, sounding quite delighted. ‘You did do the thing properly, didn’t you? Well, **Nicolas and I have had a little chat and agreed it’s all for the best.’**
>   ‘But that means he and his wife will die, won’t they?’
>   ‘They have enough Elixir stored to set their affairs in order and then, yes, they will die.’
>
> <sub><sup>HP and the Philosopher's Stone</sup></sub>

and

> **Rumour - Nicolas Flamel is going to come to Hogwarts to teach potions [in HP4]**
>
> **JKR:** *Flamel has now died; Dumbledore explained in ‘Philosopher’s Stone’ that **his old friend was going to choose death rather than allow his stone to fall into the wrong hands.***
>
> <sub><sup>[JKR Official Website - Rumours](http://web.archive.org/web/20110623030719/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/rumours_view.cfm?id=32)</sup></sub>

No mention of coercion is made.

Comment: if you read Dumbledore's dialogue in something like Don Corleone's voice "we had a little chat" suddenly starts sounding ominous, though.

Comment: @MPF - In fairness, this is a man whose formative years were spent as the lover and confidante of what would turn out to be wizardkind's greatest monsters and who clearly has no compunction about sending child soldiers to their deaths in his own long-term chess match against  the man that he kidnapped and arranged to be tutored in the evil arts.